# Can I re-ask a closed question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

I am talking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4708548/1142170) question. This seems to be OP's first question, and OP didn't show any of their work. This is why the question got closed. However, I find the question itself very interesting and would like to know the answer. I have done some work of my own and I'm wondering if I can ask this as a seperate question. I just think that the probability of OP editing the question to include their work so that the question may be reopened is low. Should I wait or can I ask this as a question of my own?

Comment: Probably it might be worth having a look at this post: [Interested in a question which is closed because of "no effort". What to do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10955) Other [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/10955) might be of interest, too. 
(With the usual caveat that the linked question is already ten years old; the site might have changed since then a bit.)

Comment: Personally, I don't see a problem with asking it again.  Cite the original, of course, and supply the context/effort that the OP didn't. If the OP ever returns to improve their post, you can delete yours.  Good mathematics should transcend weak questioners.

Comment: Another reason for the closure is like the +3 comment of Blue, asking for the definition of $\{x\}$ (I also do not know what $\{x\}$ means in this question). If you do ask this question again, then be sure to address this comment somehow.

Comment: Regarding waiting - I suggest waiting a day or two. There is no rush, and it gives the OP a chance to improve their question.

Comment: It's an intriguing question, isn't it? I had some thoughts that I'll probably flesh out more if you do repost it. Also, I think that's the notation for "fractional part of".

Comment: Rescuing questions is a noble goal, but be warned that there are haters out there – I've done it a few times, and my efforts have attracted some downvotes.

Comment: Just to say, $\{x\}$ is standard notation for the fractional part of $x$.  It's just $x-\lfloor x \rfloor$, which is to say it is $x$ minus the greatest integer which fails to exceed $x$.  This is very standard notation.

Comment: Horrible luck : I didn't check the edits to the question which had taken out some brackets. With those in place, [here's an answer to the question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1719726p11119155) on AoPS. [This post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769415/finding-values-using-the-equation-of-x-that-satisfies-left-x-right-l?noredirect=1) does the job for a specific exponent but gives the general idea away, somewhat. I also hope that you were not solving the incorrect question.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer, unfortunately I was solving the incorrect question. I found two solutions to the incorrect question: $x=1$ and $x=1+\phi.$ Interestingly, they both seem to satisfy the condition of the incorrect question.

Comment: @aqualubix The next solution to $\{x\}+\frac 1x = 1$ is $2+\sqrt{3} = 3.73205\ldots$, for which the condition of the incorrect question doesn't seem to hold from my check.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer, but it should, shouldn't it? I just realised that for $x>1,$ we can swap $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^n}$ with $\{\frac{1}{x}\}$ and $\{\frac{1}{x^n}\}$ respectively.

Comment: It should, right? Yeah, I might have made a mistake somewhere. Anyway, keeping things on topic, that question hasn't been edited and is not going to be reopened in its current form (it has two reopen votes but I would vote to close in a heartbeat if it reopened right now). I think you can ask whatever question you want to at this point of time. Use the links I provided as context if you want. The other question will go with time.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer, actually, the links you provided completely answered the question. The case of $n=3$ gives away the idea, like you said. For the general case, one needs to use the binomial theorem.

Comment: @aqualubix It's good that we've solved this eventually.